# Edittext space why space beetwhen two edittexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have linearLayout contains two EditText and set weigh() to both EditText. But the some thing problem when display to device, the space bet when 2 EditText appear. Why....

```
          <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="@string/PNR"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:hint="@string/ENTER_YOUR_PNR_CODE"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is that Image I want to design follow:
[image]

Here is the picture output ( The space between 2 Edittext I do not know why it appear? ) 
 [image]

Comment: check your image carefully by zooming it separately, might be having a default space in image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Can you try this code?

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccc"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Whant an upgrade? Enter booking details" />

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:background="#ffffff">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                android:text="PNR"
                android:padding="18dip"
                android:gravity="left" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText04"
                android:hint="Enter your pnr code"
                android:padding="18dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:gravity="left" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                android:text="Last name"
                android:padding="18dip"
                android:gravity="left" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText05"
                android:hint="enter your last name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="18dip"
                android:gravity="left" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Set transparent background color. both Edit text view try this color code

```
 android:background="#00000000"


   <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="@string/PNR"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

I think your problem is solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
android:weightSum="2"

android:layout_weight="1"

android:layout_weight="1"
```

Android UI functionality takes 8dp space for each elements.

or

Give Background as "Transparent" - This will solve your problem

Comment: not Working too...i dont think there are have a change with weight:  0.4 + 0.6 or 1 + 1

Comment: change your background layout color. Give edittext background as transparent

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine at my side.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="@string/PNR"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:hint="@string/ENTER_YOUR_PNR_CODE"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps..

**Edit**

EditText holds default padding so you need to explicitly set it 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

set EdtiText's background transparent or null
like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:text="@string/PNR"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:hint="@string/ENTER_YOUR_PNR_CODE"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```